# node can't start after vue.js-cli install

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, vue-cli

I installed node.js on a Windows machine.

Then I installed `npm i -g vue-cli`.

`npm run dev` brought up the vue.js-cli site at http://localhost:8080.

After turning off and on my computer, when I type `npm run dev`, I get this error:

[image]

**What do I need to do to get node able to server the vue.js-cli site again?**

Comment: You should have needed to run `vue init <template-name> <project-name>` to generate a project before running `npm run dev`. And this would have created the `package.json` file you're missing. Did you not do that?

Comment: Thanks, I needed to go into the my-project directory, which got me further, but now I am getting these problems with eslint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869803/why-do-eslint-errors-cause-site-not-to-display-after-vue-js-cli-install