# Why do eslint errors cause site not to display after vue.js-cli install?

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js

I installed node.js on a Windows machine.

Then I installed `npm i -g vue-cli`.

`npm run dev` brought up the vue.js-cli site at http://localhost:8080.

After turning off and on my computer, when I type `npm run dev`, I get this error:

[image]

But when I installed vuejs-cli, I explicitly stated I didn't want eslint when it offered to install it.

And there are no eslint errors in my settings:

[image]

And in my browser I see this:

[image]

Otherwise, I haven't changed the files, and it worked right after I had installed it once.

**How can I get these eslint errors to not occur and the site to display corrected?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable ESLint in vue-cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757069/how-to-disable-eslint-in-vue-cli)